# Static attribute in Session Scoped Component Bean

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, javabeans

I am newbie in Spring MVC and I have session scope component bean

```
@Component
@Scope(value="session",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class NotificationService {



static int unreadMessageCoutner;
static ArrayList<WebSocketNotificationDTO> unreadMessagesDTO;


@PostConstruct
public void  initBean(){
    this.unreadMessagesDTO = new ArrayList<WebSocketNotificationDTO>();
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroyBean(){
    this.unreadMessagesDTO.clear();
    this.unreadMessagesDTO=null;
}


@Override
public void addNotification(WebSocketNotificationDTO notification){
    this.unreadMessagesDTO.add(notification);
}

@Override
public void incrementCounter(){
    this.unreadMessageCoutner++;
}

@Override
public int getUnreadMessageCoutner(){
    return this.unreadMessageCoutner;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<WebSocketNotificationDTO> getUnreadMessages(){
    return this.unreadMessagesDTO;
}

@Override
public void setCounter(int counter){
    //To do
}
```

}

I have update the attributes of this bean single time and call these method of this bean by @autowired and now I want to get the updated value of these attribute when I call get method.

Actually now getting NULL value whenever I have autowired this bean in different @controller.

Is this any way to get the single updated value in SPRING ?

Thanks in Advance

**Note:** Every user session have different value.

Comment: Do you know what `static` does? You basically now share everything between everything. Session Scope is basically rendered useless.

Comment: static variable are class attribute that make single copy instead multiple.

Comment: Well not entirly correct, they are class scoped. Each time you create a new instance (for a session) you clear out everything for each instance. (due to your constructor). You are basically sharing state between different browser sessions. If a session is destroyed everything (for every other session as well) is cleared due to the use of `static`... I can hardly believe that is what you want... You basically have a singleton in disguise.